# How does rospy.get_time() work? Does it repeat if I restart roscore?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to collect data of different images and store them under the name as rospy.get_time(). I want to know if I stop collecting this data and restart it later, is there a chance that I will be getting the same rospy.get_time()?

How does the rospy.get_time() work? Is it based on wall clock time( and I am assuming that it is my PC's time)? Why does it always start with "14xxxxxx.xxx".

Please clarify!
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256694/how-does-rospy.get_time()-work?-does-it-repeat-if-i-restart-roscore?/) by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2017-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is it based on wall clock time

If you don't set `use_sim_time`, then: yes.

> Why does it always start with "14xxxxxx.xxx".

Because it is a *unix timestamp* which is just an integer representing "the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970" ([wikipedia/unix_timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)).

Everything *after* `1400000000` is any point in time after *2014-05-13T16:53:20+00:00* (converted [here](https://www.epochconverter.com)).

Finally, see [wiki/Clock](http://wiki.ros.org/Clock) for some more info.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1